# Setting syntax in Gvim for Assembly

Tags: syntax, assembly, vim

How can I automatically set the syntax of a certain file extension same as that of an existing language(say Perl) in Gvim ?

I know that I can do this using

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl  setf perl

I want to do it for assembly now..

seems like this is not working..
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl  setf assembly

for IA assembly

Answer (score 1):

You could try `setf asm`

To know what syntaxes you have, list `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax`.